# About Poisson Process

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, poisson-process

I'm studing the Poisson Process and i have two definitions. I got stuck on a step to proove that the two definitions are equivalent.

Can i claim this:

The solution to this differential equation is: $P_{0}(t) = e^{-\alpha t}$

$\dfrac{\dot{P}_{0}(t)}{P_{0}(t)} = \alpha$ with the initial condition: $P_{0}(0) = 1$ and $\alpha$ is a constant.

Is it true? My intuition is Yes, and correct me if i'm wrong, but the only function that satisfies that his derivative divided by the function equals a constant is the exponential function.

Thank's..

Comment: What does this have to do with the Poisson process (stochastic process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is wrong. True is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(e^{-αt}P(t))=e^{-αt}(\dot P(t)-αP(t)) = 0
$$
so that
$$
e^{-αt}P(t)=const.=P(0)
$$
so that $\dot P=αP$ has the only solution $P(t)=e^{αt}P(0)$.

You would need to change the sign before $α$ to get the opposite case.